# Allow writing to specific fields only to paid users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a document in which all users can write into, but I would like to limit writing to **specific** fields or specific data in this document **only** to paid users.

I know how to create a rule to allow writing to a certain document based on a certain field - but how to make this rule valid only when you write to a certain field? ( not any write)

```
 allow write,update: if request.resource.data.brand.userID ==  request.auth.uid;
```

How would I allow writing a certain field `logo` ( `{"logo":"me.png"}` ) to a document, only if the written document contains field `"paid":true` . (but keep allowing other fields to be written free)

Or - is there *best practice* way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your security rules you have access to the document from the DB as well. So if the document contains `paid` field, you can check it like `if resource.data.paid == true`. See [Data validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) for more details.

Since the document from the request is also available to you, the full condition should be similar to:

```
if resource.data.paid == true || !(logo in request.resource.data)
```

Comment: thanks a  lot ! is that the "right" way to do this ?

Comment: @paulseems Glad to help you! In the case you’ve described it looks like a right solution. Just make sure that the `paid` property is guarded as well, so anyone cannot update it. Actually, the rules support much more complex logic, you can even access other documents from the database or custom claims of the auth token. Beside the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) I can recommend you this [article](https://medium.com/@jek.bao.choo/my-firestore-security-rules-learning-notes-14316400f160) with a set of samples.

Comment: How can you guard a specific field from being written and allowing only Firebase Function to write to it ?

Comment: @paulseems firebase functions ignore security rules, so you can just forbid the write in the rules